# Zabbix agent can't connect to Zabbix5.0 server

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, zabbix

I installed zabbix agent on Ubuntu 18.04 server. I changed the IP address and hostname pointing to the Zabbix server in zabbix_agentd.config file in /etc. And Restart Zabbix agent. Seems like the server is running, but the agent is not conneting to the server. How can I fix it?

```
/etc/zabbix# sudo systemctl status zabbix-agent
● zabbix-agent.service - Zabbix Agent
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/zabbix-agent.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2020-07-29 15:26:30 NZST; 5s ago
  Process: 16401 ExecStop=/bin/kill -SIGTERM $MAINPID (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 16403 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/zabbix_agentd -c $CONFFILE (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 16406 (zabbix_agentd)
    Tasks: 6 (limit: 2325)
   CGroup: /system.slice/zabbix-agent.service
           ├─16406 /usr/sbin/zabbix_agentd -c /etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf
           ├─16407 /usr/sbin/zabbix_agentd: collector [idle 1 sec]
           ├─16408 /usr/sbin/zabbix_agentd: listener #1 [waiting for connection]
           ├─16409 /usr/sbin/zabbix_agentd: listener #2 [waiting for connection]
           ├─16410 /usr/sbin/zabbix_agentd: listener #3 [waiting for connection]
           └─16411 /usr/sbin/zabbix_agentd: active checks #1 [idle 1 sec]

Jul 29 15:26:29 UbuntuServe-001 systemd[1]: Starting Zabbix Agent...
Jul 29 15:26:30 UbuntuServe-001 systemd[1]: zabbix-agent.service: Can't open PID file /run/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.pid (yet?) after start: No such file or directory
Jul 29 15:26:30 UbuntuServe-001 systemd[1]: Started Zabbix Agent.
```

Comment: content of the zabbix_agentd.log ?

Answer (score 2):

> Can't open PID file /run/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.pid (yet?) after start: No such file or directory

The `/run/zabbix` directory does not exists. Remove the `PIDFILE=` line from config file, and `zabbxi` will create the pid file in temporary directory. Alternatively, create `/run/zabbix` directory and `chown` it to zabbix user.